# Get node text with HTML task inside

Tags: java, xpath

I try to examine with Java XPath an html string like this:

```
<app>
    <elem class="A">value1</elem>
    <elem class="B">value2a<br />value2b</elem>
    <elem class="C">value3</elem>
</app>
```

Actually for obtain the *elem*'s value i use this code

```
public String getValue(String xml, String classValue){
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    document = db.parse(source);

    String xpathRequest = "//*[@class='"+classValue+"']/text()";
    String value = xpath.evaluate(xpathRequest , document);

    return value;
}
```

For classes A and C works fine, but when i ask the content of task with class B obtain only `value2a`

How i can get the complete string of node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run

```
String xpathRequest = "//*[@class='"+class+"']";
String value = this.xpath.evaluate(xpathRequest , document);
```

This will select the `<elem>` node and when converted to a String build the concatenation of all text content, e.g. `Value2a Value2b`

To get a list of all text contents below a `Elem` you need to select them as NodeSet:

```
String xpathRequest = "//*[@class='"+class+"']/text()";
NodeList textNodes = (NodeList)xpath.evaluate(xpathRequest , document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i=0; i<textNodes.getLength(); i++)
    texts.add(textNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
```

Comment: tryed before post... Return `Value2aValue2b`

Comment: @dceccon: so you want the string `value2a <br /> value2b`?

Comment: Yes, or `Value2a Value2b`. The best is a list if there are one or more `<br />`

Comment: Work perfectly! Thx :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is because xpath will return 2 value at this moment. Try below :-

```
List<WebElement> allprice = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='B']/text()"));
for(WebElement a:WebElement allprice){
   System.out.println(a.gettext());
}
```

Comment: your code seems to be like selenium. I dont think he requires that.

Comment: I am just telling him that why he is getting only one result.